# c# out parameter, why I have assigned the value to my variable, still can't return?

Tags: c#, oop, scope, reference, out

I have a simple method like below,

```
        private int Increment(out n) {
            int n = 46;
            return n++;
        }
```

as my understanding, using out must initialise the variable first, but I still got the error of

```
return n++
```

> The out parameter 'n' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

I also got an error of my variable

```
int n = 46;
```

> A local or parameter named 'n' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

My question is, why I can't declare a new variable inside my method, it seems I must declare my variable outside of the method, then assigned the value inside the method.

If I just out, it means I must pass variable int to my method, can't I created inside the method? And out the parameter's pointer I declare inside my method?

Comment: `private int Increment(out n)` should be `private int Increment(out int n)` right? Then you don't have to write `int n = 46` but rather `n = 46`.

Comment: yeah, sorry I missed it, it's private int Increment(out int n).

Comment: I think I miss the purpose of your function. Is it only for educational purpose and understanding of `out`? Because this does not *Increment* anything. It just **sets** a variable to 47 and **returns** 46 (no matter how many times you call it).

Comment: @Rafalon I just wondering why I can't declare the int n inside the method, regard the variable, I think it will return 47 according to my code output. As it reference type, the output n will be 47.

Comment: Well you can't declare the int `n` because it is already declared when you write `out int n`. The "output n" will be 47, but what your function *returns* will be 46

Comment: @ckky1213 any SO user should be able to edit their own question, if you can't then it's a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The `out` declaration 'declares' the variable, you just have to **set** it in the method:

```
private int Increment(out int n)
{
    n = 46;
    return n++;
}
```

Note that this method returns 46, but `n` is 47.

Comment: Might be interesting to tell that this will *return **46*** and *set `n` to **47***

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to go a little further, `return ++n;` will both return and set n to **47**

Comment: I was tempted to add that, but I couldn't remember what that syntax is called :). Really if the method increments the passed out value it should return void..

Comment: I suppose pre-incrementing (++n) as opposed to post-incrementing (n++). You're right about returning `void`, or maybe an error-code

Comment: Initialization is usually used to refer to *assignment* combined with *declaration*. Unfortunately, the whole parameter bit is a declaration but "`out` declaration declares..." doesn't scan well. I'd still try to find different language there.

Comment: Umm.....I aware if I didn't use ref or out, just use int, and n++, it will return 46, but if use ++n, it will return 47, is anyone know why?

Comment: Because when you do `return n++;` you actually do `return n;` then `n = n+1;`. If you write `return ++n;` you do `n = n+1;` then `return n;`. This is the difference between **post-** and **pre-** incrementing

Answer (score 1):

You can write your method like this. It will return perfect output.

```
private int Increment(out int n)
{
    n = 46;
    n++;
    return n;
}
```

This will return 47 as output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but it's not the way it works.
Look at the example (its not the simplest way to increment a number it's just a POC of how the `ref` and `out` parameters work).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int incrementingNumber = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        Increment(ref incrementingNumber, out incrementingNumber);

        Console.WriteLine(incrementingNumber);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private static void Increment(ref int inNumber ,out int outNumber)
{
    outNumber = inNumber + 46;
}
```

the output is :
46
92
138
184
230
276
322
368
414
460
506
552

Comment: This doesn't show anything about `ref` (you could just as well have written the same thing without `ref` and still have the same output)

Comment: like i said poc

Comment: Okay I just realized "poc" meant "piece of code"... still you do not show how `ref` works, contrary to what you wrote. One would expect a code sample to show that it allows the function to *read* **and** *change* the value passed to it

Answer (score 0):

1. basically, you did not declare n correctly.
2. then in your function (line3), as `n` is declared already, you cannot declare it as int again.
3. your function will always return 46, because you are reassigning it in line 3 to 46
4. your function will return 46, but will set n to 47, im not sure if this is what you want.

If you want to just increment by 1 you could run this Code anywhere:

```
n++; // increment n by 1

n += 46; // increment n by 46
```

If you really want a function, I doubt that you need both, `out int n` and `return n`

this code will increment your variable n:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int n = 46;
    // some code here
    IncrementByOne(ref n);
    Console.WriteLine("N = " + n);
}    

/// this function will increment n by 1
private static void IncrementByOne(ref int n) { n++; }
```

This code will return an incremented integer

```
private static void Main ()
{
    int n = 46;
    // some code here
    n = IncrementByOne(n);
    Console.WriteLine("N = " + n);
}    

/// this function will return an integer that is incremented by 1
private static int IncrementByOne(int n)
{
    n++; //increment n by one
    return n;
}
```

If you want to declare n in your function, you have to declare it earlier

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 46; // you have to set n before incrementing
    // some code here
    IncrementByOne(out n);
    Console.WriteLine("N = " + n);
}
/// this function will always set variable n to 47
private static void IncrementBy47(out int n)
{
    n = 46; // assign n to 46
    n++; // increase n by one
}
```

This could also be shortened like:

```
/// This function will always set variable n to 47
private static void SetVarTo47(out int n) { n = 47; }
```

Hope that helps understanding what they do.

Comment: `private static void IncrementByOne(out int n) { n++; }` this is *wrong*. It should be `ref` instead of `out`. (use of unassigned parameter) and `IncrementByOne(n);` should also be `IncrementByOne(ref n);`

Comment: thank you for your additions :), implemented into my post